# Running ffmpeg script through Windows context menu

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, windows-explorer

I am trying to change the audio delay on multiple videos by 250ms. I used the following:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "video.mp4" -itsoffset -0.250 -i "video.mp4" -map 0:v -map 1:a -vcodec copy -acodec copy "video-audio-delayed.mp4"
```

However, this obviously only works with files that are named "video.mp4"

What I want to do:

Add a script to the Windows context menu with [Default Programs Editor](https://defaultprogramseditor.com) so I can right click a video file and its audio delay will be changed accordingly.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You can use `for` command to execute same command using multiple files at once.